# Terraform aws vpc module NATGW configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-template-file

This might be confusing for maintenance later. How would toggle the 3 different states (or 4 states including off)

- NATGW disabled
- single NATGW
- 1 NATGW per subnet
- 1 NATGW per AZ

```
variable "enable_nat_gateway" {
  description = "Should be true if you want to provision NAT Gateways for each of your private networks"
  default     = false
  type        = bool
}

variable "single_nat_gateway" {
  description = "Should be true if you want to provision a single shared NAT Gateway across all of your private networks"
  default     = true
  type        = bool
}

variable "one_nat_gateway_per_az" {
  description = "Should be true if you want only one NAT Gateway per availability zone. Requires `var.azs` to be set, and the number of `public_subnets` created to be greater than or equal to the number of availability zones specified in `var.azs`."
  type        = bool
  default     = false
}
```

```
module "vpc" {
  source                 = "terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws"
  name                   = var.vpc_name
  cidr                   = var.vpc_cidr
  # azs                    = slice(data.aws_availability_zones.available.names, 0, local.selected_azs)
  azs                    = slice(data.aws_availability_zones.available.names, 0, local.selected_azs)
  private_subnets        = var.ath_private_subnet_block
  public_subnets         = var.ath_public_subnet_block
  enable_nat_gateway     = var.enable_nat_gateway
  single_nat_gateway     = var.single_nat_gateway
  one_nat_gateway_per_az = var.one_nat_gateway_per_az
}


resource "aws_eip" "nat" {
  vpc = true
}
```

How can configure between the 4 modes using a single variable:

- NATGW disabled
- single NATGW
- 1 NATGW per subnet
- 1 NATGW per AZ

Comment: Sorry, your question is not clear. What's wrong with the current code? Any errors?

Comment: If you notice, I declared 3 variables for the nat gateway configuration.
1. enable_nat_gateway
2. single_nat_gateway
3. one_nat_gateway_per_az

my question is how can set up a single variable to configure between the 4 modes?
 
1. NATGW disabled
2. single NATGW
3. NATGW per subnet
4. NATGW per AZ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would hide all details of the states in the `local` variable, and create only one variable called `natgw_configuration` that is the input of your script:

```
variable "natgw_configuration" {
  type = string
  default = "NATGW_disabled"
}


locals {

  # example values of the paramters. You have to setup
  # correct values of each state you want
  natgw_states = {
    "NATGW_disabled" = {
      enable_nat_gateway = true
      single_nat_gateway = false
      one_nat_gateway_per_az = false      
    }
    "single_NATGW" = {
      enable_nat_gateway = false
      single_nat_gateway = false
      one_nat_gateway_per_az = false      
    }
    "1_NATGW_per_subnet" = {
      enable_nat_gateway = false
      single_nat_gateway = true
      one_nat_gateway_per_az = false      
    }
    "1_NATGW_per_AZ" = {
      enable_nat_gateway = false
      single_nat_gateway = true
      one_nat_gateway_per_az = true      
    }      
  }
}
```

then you use it as follows:

```
module "vpc" {
  source                 = "terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws"
  #...
  enable_nat_gateway     = local.natgw_states[var.natgw_configuration].enable_nat_gateway
  single_nat_gateway     = local.natgw_states[var.natgw_configuration].single_nat_gateway
  one_nat_gateway_per_az = local.natgw_states[var.natgw_configuration].one_nat_gateway_per_az
}
```

Comment: Can you suggest improvement on azs.   "azs  = slice(data.aws_availability_zones.available.names, 0, local.selected_azs)"  What I want to achieve is that I can control asz from local state.

 variable az_throttle_limit {
    type = int
    default = 0
    description = "number of AZs to limit to, 0 for all"
}

local variable
    selected_azs = map( data.avaialbility_zones.name)

Comment: @rudder Could you make new question with proper code and example regarding the new issue with AZs?

Comment: sure, can. I making it now

Comment: I created a new question
https://stackoverflow.com/q/74037034/20218127