# limit AZs aws_availability_zones using terraform aws vpc module

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

```
CIDR = 10.50.0.0/16

variable "region" {
  default     = "us-east-1"
  description = "AWS region"
}


data "aws_availability_zones" "available" {}
```

us-east-1 have 6 Azs.

```
["us-east-1a", "us-east-1b", "us-east-1c", "us-east-1d", "us-east-1e", "us-east-1f"]
```

I want to create 1 public and 1 private subnet per AZ configured.

I got 3 environment (dev/stage/prod)

For

1. dev env, I want to create subnet on 3 availability zones
2. stage env, on 4 availability zones
3. prod env on all availability zones. for this us-east-1 region have 6 availability_zones.

local.tf

```
locals {
  selected_azs = map(data.avaialbility_zones.name[3])
}
```

vpc.tf

```
module "vpc" {
  source                 = "terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws"
  name                   = var.vpc_name
  cidr                   = var.vpc_cidr
  azs                    = data.aws_availability_zones.available.names
  private_subnets        = var.ath_private_subnet_block
  public_subnets         = var.ath_public_subnet_block
  enable_nat_gateway     = local.natgw_states[var.natgw_configuration].enable_nat_gateway
  single_nat_gateway     = local.natgw_states[var.natgw_configuration].single_nat_gateway
  one_nat_gateway_per_az = local.natgw_states[var.natgw_configuration].one_nat_gateway_per_az
  tags                   = var.resource_tags
}
```

variable.tf

```
variable "az_throttle_limit" {
  type        = number
  default     = 0
  description = "number of AZs to limit to, 0 for all"
}
```

**Any advice on reading availability zones, How Can I control from the local state.**

Default  will create a subnet for all **availability zones on the current** region

**summary:**

- Target AZs: all “opt-in-not-required” AZs.

  (us-east-1a, us-east-1b, us-east-1c, us-east-1d, us-east-1e, us-east-1f)
- AZ’s should not be a static list, and should be automatically get from aws
- Configurable: limit # of AZs to limit resources used (especially in non-production environment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have new variable called `env` with local variable having different AZs for each `env`:

```
variable "env" {
  type = string
  default = "dev"
}


locals {
  selected_azs = {
    "dev" = [for i in range(3): data.aws_availability_zones.available.names[i]]
    "stage" = [for i in range(4): data.aws_availability_zones.available.names[i]]
   "prod" = data.aws_availability_zones.available.names
  }
}
```

then use it:

```
azs   = locals.selected_azs[var.env]
```

Comment: locals {
  total_azs = data.aws_availability_zones.available.names
  selected_azs = var.az_throttle_limit >= count(local.total_azs) ? local.total_azs : slice(local.total_azs, 0, var.az_throttle_limit)
}

I wrote this but got error

Comment: Error: Reference to undeclared local value
│
│   on local.tf line 25, in locals:
│   25:   selected_azs = var.az_throttle_limit >= local.count ? local.total_azs : slice(local.total_azs, 0, var.az_throttle_limit)        
│
│ A local value with the name "total_azs" has not been declared.
╵
╷
│ Error: Reference to undeclared local value
│
│   on local.tf line 25, in locals:
│   25:   selected_azs = var.az_throttle_limit >= local.count ? local.total_azs : slice(local.total_azs, 0, var.az_throttle_limit)        
│
│ A local value with the name "total_azs" has not been declared.

Comment: @rudder Not sure what you are doing. My code does not include `local.total_azs` variable. If you changed something, its better to make new question with your new code and errors.

Comment: can you have a look on it https://stackoverflow.com/q/74050336/20218127

Comment: @rudder Sure, but what about the current issue with selected_azs you posted?

Comment: It's working fine. But i tried different way