# Count data.aws_availability_zones.available.names error, │ There is no function named "count"

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I trying to create dynamic azs but Getting this error,

```
locals {
  total_azs    = data.aws_availability_zones.available.names
  selected_azs = var.az_throttle_limit >= count(local.total_azs) ? local.total_azs : slice(local.total_azs, 0, var.az_throttle_limit)
}
```

```
variable "az_throttle_limit" {
  type        = number
  default     = 0
  description = "number of AZs to limit to, 0 for all"
}



module "vpc" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws"
  version = "3.16.0"
  cidr    = var.vpc_cidr
  azs     = local.selected_azs
  ......
}
```

ERROR

```bash
│ Error: Call to unknown function
│
│   on local.tf line 25, in locals:
│   25:   selected_azs = var.az_throttle_limit >= count(local.total_azs) ? local.total_azs : slice(local.total_azs, 0, var.az_throttle_limit)
│     ├────────────────
│     │ local.total_azs will be known only after apply
│
│ There is no function named "count".
```

Improvement using the length function

```
locals {
  total_azs    = data.aws_availability_zones.available.names
  selected_azs = var.az_throttle_limit >= length(local.total_azs) ? local.total_azs : slice(local.total_azs, 0, var.az_throttle_limit)
}
```

The statement will always be true unless your throttle is 0

Ooohh which now brings up the bug, I did not account for throttle limit 0 (no limit)

```
 Error: Error in function call
│
│   on .terraform\modules\vpc\main.tf line 365, in resource "aws_subnet" "public":
│  365:   availability_zone_id            = length(regexall("^[a-z]{2}-", element(var.azs, count.index))) == 0 ? element(var.azs, count.index) : null
│     ├────────────────
│     │ count.index is 3
│     │ var.azs is empty list of string
│
│ Call to function "element" failed: cannot use element function with an empty list.
╵
╷
│ Error: Error in function call
│
│   on .terraform\modules\vpc\main.tf line 365, in resource "aws_subnet" "public":
│  365:   availability_zone_id            = length(regexall("^[a-z]{2}-", element(var.azs, count.index))) == 0 ? element(var.azs, count.index) : null
│     ├────────────────
│     │ count.index is 0
│     │ var.azs is empty list of string
│
│ Call to function "element" failed: cannot use element function with an empty list.
╵
╷
│ Error: Error in function call
│
│   on .terraform\modules\vpc\main.tf line 365, in resource "aws_subnet" "public":
│  365:   availability_zone_id            = length(regexall("^[a-z]{2}-", element(var.azs, count.index))) == 0 ? element(var.azs, count.index) : null
│     ├────────────────
```

Any thoughts ?

Comment: Maybe something like `selected_azs = var.az_throttle_limit >= count(local.total_azs) ? local.total_azs : var.az_throttle_limit == 0 ? slice(local.total_azs, 0, length(local.total_azs - 1)) : slice(local.total_azs, 0, var.az_throttle_limit)`.

Comment: But it seems too complicated, maybe you should consider reworking the logic about how to handle allowing all the AZs.

Comment: I fixed it by adding one more var. 

```
locals {
  total_azs = data.aws_availability_zones.available.names
  num_desired_azs = var.az_throttle_limit != 0 ? var.az_throttle_limit : length(local.total_azs) // if throttle disabled, use total number of azs
  selected_azs = local.num_desired_azs >= length(local.total_azs) ? local.total_azs : slice(local.total_azs, 0, local.num_desired_azs)
}
```